# Database in a C++ Program

Tags: c++, database, local

I've got a C++ program that needs to deal with a lot of typical database problems - looking at tables, inserting and deleting values, searching for records. All of the database information has to be stored locally. Let me emphasise that - I don't want to communicate with a server, I want the information to be stored on the user's computer.

Are there any libraries that can easily implement all this functionality, preferably in a SQL style syntax? Or what are some ways to easily and robustly implement this functionality?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [embedded DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database).

I think SQLite is one of the more popular ones.

Answer (score 2):

My personal preference would be SOCI, with a SQLite backend.

http://soci.sourceforge.net/

http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/backends/sqlite3.html

http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: I have also evaluated SOCI but ended with OTL (http://otl.sourceforge.net/). The OTL project seems to be more actively maintained and was much faster for my type of db operations. The interface may not be as handy as the SOCI interface but everything seemd to be more robust.